# Realloc manipulating data out of its scope

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, realloc

I am experiencing a very unusual behaviour from my C code. I am implementing a min and max heap that should dynamically change size if the heap capacity has reached. The issue is that the when I call `realloc` to increase the elements array of the heap, it acts in the following manner (assume both heaps are at max capacity):

1. If I add a new element in only one of the heaps, the reallocation works perfectly.
2. If i add a new element in both of the heaps (one after the other), the second one gets reallocated perfectly, but the data of the first one gets corrupted with some garbage values and some zeroes.

Please see the relevant functions below. (The problem happens with the 8th and 9th line of the main function).

I do not undestand why the calling of the `insert` function on a different heap could change the values of the previous one.

I don't know if the realloc function is messing up or my printing function. Thank You for your help.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define leftChild(x) (x << 1)
#define rightChild(x) ((x << 1) + 1)
#define parent(x) (x >> 1)


typedef int T;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    T *elements;
}   Heap;

void swap(Heap *heap, int a, int b) {
    T temp = heap->elements[a];
    heap->elements[a] = heap->elements[b];
    heap->elements[b] = temp;
}

Heap *newHeap(int capacity) {
    Heap *heap = malloc(sizeof(Heap));
    heap->capacity = capacity;
    heap->size = 0;
    heap->elements = malloc(sizeof(T) * (capacity + 1));
    return heap;
}

void increaseKey(Heap *heap, int i, T key) {
    heap->elements[i] = key;
    while (i > 1 && heap->elements[parent(i)] < heap->elements[i]) {
        swap(heap, parent(i), i);
        i = parent(i);
    }
}

void decreaseKey(Heap *heap, int i, T key) {
    heap->elements[i] = key;
    while (i > 1 && heap->elements[parent(i)] > heap->elements[i]) {
        swap(heap, parent(i), i);
        i = parent(i);
    }
}

void insert(Heap *heap, T key, bool isMinHeap) {
    if (heap->size >= heap->capacity) {
        heap->elements = realloc(heap->elements, heap->capacity * 2);
        heap->capacity = heap->capacity * 2;
    }
    heap->size++;
    heap->elements[heap->size] = 0;
    if (isMinHeap) decreaseKey(heap, heap->size, key);
    else increaseKey(heap, heap->size, key);
}

void printHeap(Heap *heap) {
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for (i = 1; i < heap->size; i++) {
        printf("%d,", heap->elements[i]);
    }
    if (heap->size != 0) {
        printf("%d", heap->elements[heap->size]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(void) {
    Heap *minHeap = newHeap(5);
    Heap *maxHeap = newHeap(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        insert(minHeap, i, true);
        insert(maxHeap, i, false);
    }
    printf("now start\n");
    insert(minHeap, 10, true);
    insert(maxHeap, 10, false);
    printHeap(minHeap);
    printHeap(maxHeap);
}
```

Comment: What is `parent(i)` in `decreaseKey()`?

Comment: What is `swap()` and `parent()`? You posted so much code, 3 more lines to add the `#include`s would not make a difference.

Comment: *I don't know if the realloc function is messing up or my printing function.*  What's your OS?  Windows?  Linux?  How many hundreds of millions if not billions of copies of the `realloc()` you are likely using are being used **all over planet Earth**? The heat death of the universe is more likely to happen before you uncover a bug in such a widely-used implementation of a function that's used as much as `realloc()`.

Comment: You frequently access `heap->elements[heap->size]`, which is out of bounds. (Yes, I know that you allocated memory for one more slot just to be sure, but it feels (and probably is) wrong.) Oh, and you need the `sizeof(T)` in your realloc, just as with `malloc`.

Comment: @mch sorry, i thought i included all of it. Please find the most up to date code in the recent edit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i am sure the bug is in my code, I just dont know where.... My OS is MacOS 10.14.3

Comment: @MOehm I am allocating one more spot so that i can neatly use bit shifting to access parent, left child and right child

Comment: There's nothing "neat" about the bit-shifting and I don't see how an uninitialised extra slot at the end will help you there. (If you mean that the 1-based indexing is "neater" in this case, go nuts. But if you want to leave `a[0]` blank and use `a[size]`, then you must also re-allocate accordingly: `realloc(s, sizeof(T) * (size + 1))`.)

Comment: @MOehm yea changing that worked. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major bugs in your (otherwise quite tidy) program:

First, you must supply a size in bytes to `malloc` and `realloc`, which means that there should be a `sizeof(T)` somewhere unless you allocate arrays of `char`. You do that when you allocate the initial array, but forgot it when re-allocating.

Second, you use a one-based index to access the array. In C, arrays are zero-based. That also applies to data allocated on the heap. The first index is `0` and the last valid index is `heap->size - 1`.

That means thet when you append an element, you use the current size as insertion index and then increase the size. (Of course you must check whether tere is space first, but you do that.) So:

```
// ... allocate if necessary ...

heap->elements[heap->size] = 0;
if (isMinHeap) decreaseKey(heap, heap->size, key);
else increaseKey(heap, heap->size, key);

heap->size++;
```

That is a common pattern and is often seen when appending stuff to an array: `array[size++] = stuff;`.

Finally, you will probably have to update the functions that determine the parent and children:

```
parent(n) == (n - 1) / 2;
left(n) == 2*n + 1;
right(n) == 2*n + 2;
```

Don't forget to `free` your memory after you've used it.

Comment: changing the `realloc` call to include `sizeof(T)` did the trick for me. I tried the solution with the 1 based indexing and it still works (I know its not the C way but it keeps the bit shifts nice and neat). Thanks a lot for your help. I still dont understand why the program worked if there was only one call to insert (case 1 in my question). Anyways thanks a lot for your help.